# Gradle Application Plugin - Building multiple start scripts / dists for the same project with different mainClassName

Tags: gradle

We have a Gradle project using the java plugin that has a couple of command line tools it needs to build.  The project is just packaged up into a jar with its dependencies.  We'd then like a couple of start scripts to kick off the various entry points in that project for each of these tools.

Naturally the *application* plugin is a good choice.  And so we changed **java** to **application** and provided a `mainClassName` to create start scripts and tar distributable's.  This worked to create a single application jar, but only one set of start scripts that used the *mainClassName* specified.

How can we create multiple start scripts for different entry points? (different `mainClassName`'s?)

One approach I tried was creating some subprojects that had the *application* plugin applied and specified the individual mainClassNames seperatately

```groovy
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
        
    repositories { 
        // maven repos           
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.thirdparty:somejar:1.0'
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
}


subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'application'
}
    
project(':tools:csvLoader') {
    mainClassName = 'com.demo.tools.csvLoader.Loader'
}

project(':tools:summariser') {
    mainClassName = 'com.demo.tools.summary.Summarise'
}
```

And referenced in the root projects settings.gradle

```groovy
include "tools","tools:csvLoader","tools:summariser"
```

This worked - but each subproject creates an identical jar (just named with the name of the subproject) and each subdir build folder holds a copy of that jar plus another copy of all the dependencies.  Thats feels a little wasteful.  It could also be confusing to a new developer seeing the subprojects there with all these tasks and no code whatsoever.

Is there a better way go about telling gradle to make multiple application related tasks but changing the mainClassName for each without having to resort to creating empty subprojects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always drop down to the task level and declare/configure/wire the necessary tasks yourself, or declare additional tasks on top of what `apply plugin: "application"` provides. See the [application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N1477D) chapter in the Gradle user guide for which related tasks are available.

Comment: i am in the exact same situation as depicted in the question. Peter, are you suggesting to extend on the functionality provided in the application plugin in order to be able to create multiple start scripts? can you elaborate? Neversleepz, did you go with Peter's idea or did you accept the "wasteful" jars solution?

Comment: @JesChergui we actually dropped the requirement, but I understood the solution to be define something like `task mySecondAppNeedsAStartScript(type: CreateStartScripts) { ... }`
`
CreateStartScripts is documented here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.application.CreateStartScripts.html

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way to generate multiple start scripts with Gradle's `application` plugin:

```groovy
mainClassName = "com.example.PrimaryEntryPoint"

startScripts {
  applicationName = 'primary'
}

// For convenience, define a map of additional start scripts.
// Key is script name and value is Java class.
def extraStartScripts = [
    'secondary' : 'com.example.SecondaryEntryPoint',
    'tertiary'  : 'com.example.TertiaryEntryPoint'
]

// Create a task for each additional entry point script.
extraStartScripts.each { scriptName, driverClass ->
  Task t = task(scriptName + "-script",
       group: 'CLI Script Generation',
       type: CreateStartScripts) {
    mainClassName = driverClass
    applicationName = scriptName
    outputDir = startScripts.outputDir
    classpath = startScripts.classpath
  }
  startScripts.dependsOn(t)
}
```