# Gradle application plugin with multiple main classes

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using the gradle 'application' plugin to start my application. This works well.
Now I want to add the option to start a different main class in the same project. Can I change the plugin's configuration to allow that?

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "net.worcade.my.MainClass"
```

Comment: What is the condition that you want to base this conditional config on?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. A command line parameter, a `-D` argument...

Comment: But there must be some condition in which you want this to be main class..what is that?

Comment: In my IDE, I'd just make two run targets, one for each main class. So the first one could call `gradle run first` and the second one could call `gradle run second`.

Comment: If that's all you need, you can either run the class directly from the IDE, without going through gradle, or add two tasks of type JavaExec to your build file. https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html

Comment: Have you worked it out? What's your scenario?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/09/gradle-goodness-run-java-application.html

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task(runSimple, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
   main = 'com.mrhaki.java.Simple'
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
   args 'mrhaki'
   systemProperty 'simple.message', 'Hello '
}
```

Clearly then what you can change:

- runSimple can be named whatever you want
- set main as appropriate
- clear out args and systemProperty if not needed

To run:

```
gradle runSimple
```

You can put as many of these as you like into your build.gradle file.

Comment: If you want to pass arguments from the command line you can do this with:

`gradle runSimple --args 'arg1 arg2'`

(You'll need to remove the `args` bit from the `task()` obviously)

Answer (score 9):

You can directly configure the Application Plugin with properties:

```
application {
    mainClassName = project.findProperty("chooseMain").toString()
}
```

And after in command line you can pass the name of the main class:

```
./gradlew run -PchooseMain=net.worcade.my.MainClass
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you can generate multiple start scripts if you need to package your apps

```kotlin
application {
    applicationName = "myapp"
    mainClassName = "my.Main1"
}
tasks.named<CreateStartScripts>("startScripts") {
    applicationName = "myapp-main1"
}
val main2StartScripts by tasks.register("main2StartScripts", CreateStartScripts::class) {
    applicationName = "myapp-main2"
    outputDir = file("build/scripts") // By putting these scripts here, they will be picked up automatically by the installDist task
    mainClassName = "my.Main2"
    classpath = project.tasks.getAt(JavaPlugin.JAR_TASK_NAME).outputs.files.plus(project.configurations.getByName(JavaPlugin.RUNTIME_CLASSPATH_CONFIGURATION_NAME)) // I took this from ApplicationPlugin.java:129
}
tasks.named("installDist") {
    dependsOn(main2StartScripts)
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. What about re-using the classpath value that the application plugin has set for the standard `startScripts` task? I could do so by using `classpath = tasks.startScripts.get().classpath` and the same with `outdir`. And it is probably also possible to let `startScripts` depend on the custom task, right? Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59724219/1804173).

Answer (score 1):

Use `javaExec` task to handle it :

```
task run(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    if (project.hasProperty('chooseMain')){
        if (chooseMain == 'Main1'){
            main = 'application.Main1'
        } else if (chooseMain == 'second'){
            main = 'application.Main2'
        }
    } else {
        println 'please pass the main name'
    }
}
```

And from the command line pass your option in that way :

```
gradle run -PchooseMain=first
```

Comment: `main` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gradle's `tasks.register` function](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:defining_tasks) and `JavaExec` in your `build.gradle` file to add another `run` task.

In this example, `gradle runMain2` will build and run your application's `net.worcade.my.MainClass2` class.

```java
tasks.register('runMain2', JavaExec) {
    dependsOn 'classes'
    mainClass = 'net.worcade.my.MainClass2'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```