# How to package a Java app with multiple entrypoints

Tags: java, docker, gradle, jar

I've been struggling to understand how to package our app so we can run multiple commands in one Docker image.

**Our set-up**

`bootstrap/Main` is a [picocli](https://picocli.info/) entrypoint which registers other commands, i.e. `HttpServer`, `CliCommandOne`, `CliCommandTwo`, etc. These commands can be defined in other modules/packages. The app is packaged as a JAR with Gradle application plugin. By default, without parameters, `HttpServer` command will be used. It is possible, because in `HttpServer` command we can start an HTTP server explicitly (we're using https://jooby.io/ framework now).

The Docker image is deployed to k8s. So we have a server running, and at the same time, we can `exec` into the container and run another CLI command.

**The problem**

We want to switch to another framework, e.g. Quarkus, Micronaut or Spring. And it looks like those frameworks either allow you to start an HTTP server (or WebSocket) or create a CLI command, but there is no way to replicate what we have now, i.e. package multiple commands in one JAR and be able to start them in one Docker image.

**Solutions we thought of**

What I can think of is an approach that Kafka is using: they have one JAR, as far as I understand, and then use a lot of `sh` scripts (https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/bin) to run different classes https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-run-class.sh. This seems like too customized for us.

We can, of course, generate separate JARs for every class with `main` method, and then create different Docker images and somehow find a way to run them. But that seems like an overhead in terms of Docker images. What if we need 20 commands?

So I'm looking for a way how to we package the app in order to have multiple executable "commands". I'm not even sure, if it's a good idea. Would be glad to hear about possible options or best practices.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the concrete problem is. A jar can contain as many classes as you want, and each class can contain a main method. And even if you have one main method only, what prevents you to use an argument or a system property or whatever in this main method to decide what to do (i.e. run a Spring app, or a Micronaut app, or whataver you want)?

Comment: Or you can make one main class with a main method that reads the first command-line argument and based on this argument forwards the remaining arguments to one of several other main methods in different classes.

Comment: If you decide you want one JAR with multiple start scripts, you can do that with Gradle's `application` plugin. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59724219/611819

Comment: > use an argument or a system property or whatever in this main method to decide what to do

Comment: That's kinda what we do now with picocli. And we can do that because our HTTP framework can be started explicitly by `app.run()`. But with other frameworks I cannot find a way to do that. I'm just not that experienced with them. Basically, I'm looking for a way in Quarkus or Micronaut to do something like `webserver.run()` so I can execute it based on a parameter I get in command line. By reading the docs of these frameworks, it looks to me that they do that implicitely, after you run packaged JAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do that in Micronaut.

Controller:

```
@Controller("/hello")
public class MyController {
    @Get(produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

HTTP server command:

```
@Command(name = "http-server", description = "Starts HTTP server")
public class HttpApp implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Micronaut.run(HttpApp.class);
    }
}
```

Cli command example:

```
@Command(name = "cli-one", description = "test cli command one")
public class CliCommandOne implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("hello from CliCommandOne");
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
@Command(name = "main-command",
        description = "Description of a main command",
        mixinStandardHelpOptions = true,
        subcommands = {HttpApp.class, CliCommandOne.class})
public class Application implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("hello from CLI main command");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PicocliRunner.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Get help with all available commands (with Gradle):

```
› gw run --args='--help'
11:37:20.928 [main] INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [cli]
Usage: main-command [-hV] [COMMAND]
Description of a main command
  -h, --help      Show this help message and exit.
  -V, --version   Print version information and exit.
Commands:
  http-server  Starts HTTP server
  cli-one      test cli command one
```

Run CliCommandOne:

```
› gw run --args='cli-one'
11:37:32.423 [main] INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [cli]
hello from CliCommandOne
```

Start HTTP server:

```
gw run --args='http-server'
11:37:40.491 [main] INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [cli]
11:37:41.263 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 307ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8081
<=========----> 75% EXECUTING [2s]
```